# Playing an ArrayList of MediaPlayer objects

Tags: java, arraylist, javafx, listener, media

Context:

I'm making a game with a huge group of people for a uni project, and I want to make a music class where someone can write `Music music = New Music("song1.mp3, song2.mp3, song3.mp3")`  and  `music.play()` somewhere else and it will play those songs in order and forever. The files must be stored in a particular location, my code at the moment takes care of this. I want it to be this way so it's easy for others to put their own music into the program for whatever area of the game they're implementing (the tutors will like me doing this).

At the moment my code initializes with

```
private ArrayList<MediaPlayer> playlist;

public Music(ArrayList<String> playlistStrings){
    playlist = new ArrayList<MediaPlayer>();
    for(int i = 0; i<playlistStrings.size(); i++){
        URL url = Music.class.getResource("../Music/" + playlistStrings.get(i));
        Media media = new Media(url.toString());
        MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer(media);
        playlist.add(player);
    }
    System.out.println(playlist);
}
```

---

tl;dr

I have an ArrayList of MediaPlayer objects and I want to play them all, and loop the entire playlist. I understand I'm supposed to use a Listener at some point... but I'm still confused because I want to have a listener but I also want it in some kind of loop... Does anyone have an example of this somewhere? 
I have already looked at 
https://gist.github.com/jewelsea/1446612
and extracted his playlist code, but it did not work for me. 
Thanks!

edit: The following code can play a list of tracks, but I can't figure out how to get the entire list to repeat indefinitely.

```
public void play(){
    System.out.println(trackIndex);
    player = playlist.get(trackIndex); 
    player.play();
    player.setOnEndOfMedia(new Runnable() {
        @Override public void run() {
            System.out.println(trackIndex);
            player.stop(); 
            if(trackIndex == (playlist.size()-1)){
                trackIndex = 0;
            }
            trackIndex++;
            player = playlist.get(trackIndex);
            player.play();
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Fixed this using a recursive call to the method..